# Python Newbie: Calculating with two lists one of it a 2d list

Tags: python

Yeah, first of all i'm a Python Newbie.
I've got the task to code something similiar, more easier variant of the analytic hierarchy process (ahp).
I'm not allowed to take any packages like numpy.

I need a list input [n*m] like:

```
liste = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0],[7.0,8.0,9.0]]
```

I've realised it like this:

```
liste = input("Put in the Matrix: ")
```

I need to sum up the Columns:

```
 col_sums = [ sum(x) for x in zip(*liste) ]
```

Now it need to calc the normalized list, it looks like this:

```
liste = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],
        [4.0,5.0,6.0],
        [7.0,8.0,9.0]]

list_norm = 1.0/col_sums[0] 2.0/col_sums[1] ...
            4.0/col_sums[0] 5.0/col_sums[1] ...
            7.0/col_sums[0] 8.0/col_sums[1] ...
```

What is the proper way to realize it?

Thank's for your feedback & attention.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us what you've coded and, if needed, ask why that does not work. And [please avoid acute accent (´) and use an apostrophe (') instead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163480/which-is-the-correct-apostrophe-to-use-when-typing-quote-or-backtick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing everything else so far looks right. You just need another list comprehension for `list_norm`:

```
liste = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],
        [4.0,5.0,6.0],
        [7.0,8.0,9.0]]
col_sums = [ sum(x) for x in zip(*liste) ]
list_norm = [[e / col_sums[c] for c, e in enumerate(row)] for row in liste]
# [[0.083, 0.133, 0.166], 
#  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333], 
#  [0.583, 0.533, 0.5]]
```

We use `enumerate()` to get both the element and its list index here, and use the index to get the appropriate sum from `col_sums`.

Alternate, cleaner, solution, as mentioned by @kaya3 in a comment:

```
list_norm = [[e / s for e, s in zip(row, col_sums)] for row in liste]
```

where `zip()` produces the pairs of corresponding elements from both of its arguments. Functionally, this is the same snippet of code, and produces the same thing.

---

There aren't any particularly clean ways to get the entire process in one line, but I would argue it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Thank you, that´s a proper solution. I´ve added the round() fnc.
`list_norm = [[round(e / col_sums[c], 4) for c, e in enumerate(row)] for row in liste]`

Comment: @kaya3 I don´t understand this code example, can you please be more clear?

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for pointing that out, it's a better solution. I've edited it into my answer accordingly